# Secure authentication for REST or GraphQL Single-page application

Tags: authentication, single-page-application

I'm working on a new SPA with a GraphQL backend. What I'm not sure about is how to properly solve authentication between the JS client and GraphQL backend. For the purpose of authentication it doesn't really matter if the backend is GraphQL or good old REST.

I read some articles and other questions here on StackOverflow. Here are the possible solutions I gathered and their problems:

### Cookies

Well of course cookies are vulnerable to CSRF attacks. So maybe cookies could be used with some additional CSRF protection. I couldn't find how to implement it in this case though. How to create and use CSRF tokens in a SPA?

### JWTs (JSON Web Tokens)

Apparently JWTs have many problems and should not be used:

- https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/03/jwt-json-web-tokens-is-bad-standard-that-everyone-should-avoid
- http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/
- http://cryto.net/%7Ejoepie91/blog/2016/06/19/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions-part-2-why-your-solution-doesnt-work/

### Some other tokens

This is what most REST APIs do - the client sends an authentication token usually in a X-Auth-Token header. This of course doesn't have the CSRF vulnerability of cookies but is not entirely suitable for SPA (REST APIs were usually not designed for SPA frontend applications). It shares some of the problems with JWTs - mainly that the token needs to be stored in a LocalStorage on the client side. (Explained in the [article](http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/) about JWTs linked above.)

---

The problem is that I always found just some critique why solution X is wrong with no information what to use instead or with a recommendation to use solution Y with no regard to the problems of that solution.

Many websites are saying that the API should be stateless - not saving any data about currently authenticated sessions because it prevents horizontal scaling. I don't really share this concern - 99% of applications don't need horizontal scaling anyway.

**So what is the best practice for SPA authentication? What solution are you using in your SPAs?**

I'm not necessarily disregarding all the solutions listed above but if any of them should be used I need to solve their problems somehow or have a very good reason to disregard the problems.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to authentication, there are a lot of really smart but angry people fight against pretty much any concept ever, and you're right, often they forget the part where they should recommend an alternative.

OAuth 2 has been crapped on by a lot of people, but it is indeed absolutely fantastic, so long as you use SSL!

There's a whole chapter explaining the pros and cons of all the authentication types one of my books: [Build APIs You Won't Hate](https://leanpub.com/build-apis-you-wont-hate)